# Xcode3 to Xcode4 code templates

Tags: xcode, xcode4, xcode3to4

can someone tell me how to convert code templates from xcode3 to xcode4?
I am reading article at http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/04/opengl-es-from-ground-up-part-2-look-at.html and author offers his OpenGLES code template, but I can't get it working in new xcode4, seems it have different format. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Did you find a solution? It does not seem to be trivial as described here http://blog.boreal-kiss.net/2011/03/11/a-minimal-project-template-for-xcode-4/

Comment: Nope, I didn't. At the moment xcode4 have many shortcomings that drive me mad, so I decided to switch back to xcode3 :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem, here is a list of the changes you need to do to make your xcode 3 templates works with xcode 4 :

First you have to move your templates to a new directory :

/YourUserDirectory/Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates/File Templates

(previously it was /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/File Templates)

Then you need to :

- rename your templates from "*.pbfiletemplate" to ".xctemplate"
- rename class.h into `___FILEBASENAME___`.h (the class.m can stay unchanged)
- inside all of your files change «FILEBASENAMEASIDENTIFIER» into `___FILEBASENAMEASIDENTIFIER___`
- Additonaly all the key words like «FILENAME», «PROJECTNAME», need to be replaced by `___FILENAME___`, `___PROJECTNAME___`, etc
- «OPTIONALHEADERIMPORTLINE» needs to be replaced by #import "`___FILEBASENAME___.h`"

Hope this helps,
Vincent

Comment: Apple will (probably) delete those files when you upgrade. You want to put them into "~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates/File Templates" instead. (confirmed working for me - Xcode4 picks them up from that location)

Comment: This directory does not exist, did you create it ?

Comment: Yes - as soon as you create it, Xcode4 finds it - you don't even have to restart, it's all automatic and immediate :)

Comment: Apple moved it again in 4.3 . . . does anyone have the new location?

Comment: Actually, Apple didnt "remove it" - they BROKE IT. For no apparent reason - I guess they just didnt bother testing. Now, if Apple finds a template that replaces a system template, they just say "NO!" and ignore your templates. Great. Thanks, Apple. You have to rename all your template folders to make them show up :(

Answer (score 2):

Until XCode 4 is finalised, there's probably not much point in this. However, you can side by side install XCode 3 and 4 and the XCode project format is compatible between them. Hence, I'd just install the template in XCode 3, create your new project(s), then open the results in XCode 4.